# GCE doesn't create HTTP load balancer

Tags: google-compute-engine

When creating an HTTP load balancer in google compute engine, I receive the following error:

> The resource
>   'projects/byclosure-infrastructure/global/backendServices' was not
>   found

Comment: Yes, it doesn't have this error.

Comment: Can you provide the command that you're using to create the backend service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: Google has fixed the problem, the error isn't occurring any more and the http load balancer is created.